# exec $SHELL from bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, shell, vagrant

Trying to create a vagrant provision script for installing rails in ubuntu machine as in https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
apt-get update
apt-get -y install redis-server
apt-get -y install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev

git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash

rbenv install 2.2.1
rbenv global 2.2.1
ruby -v

echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
gem install bundler

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update

gem install rails -v 4.2.0
rbenv rehash
rails -v

sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-common
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-9.3 libpq-dev
```

Script fails at `exec $SHELL`
Additionally ruby version is not `2.2.1`, but the default one from ubuntu  ruby `1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786)`

Comment: When you do `exec somecommand` the script is replaced with the command, so the rest of the script never executes.

Comment: The commads on the web page you linked to are intended to be run interactively. That allows you to keep typing to the new shell that replaces the original shell. It doesn't work the same way in a script.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks, but can I do the same from a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a here-doc to get the rest of the script passed as input when you exec a new shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
apt-get update
apt-get -y install redis-server
apt-get -y install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev

git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL <<EOF1

git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL <<EOF2

git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv-gem-rehash.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/rbenv-gem-rehash

rbenv install 2.2.1
rbenv global 2.2.1
ruby -v

echo "gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc" > ~/.gemrc
gem install bundler

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update

gem install rails -v 4.2.0
rbenv rehash
rails -v

sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-common
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-9.3 libpq-dev
EOF2
EOF1
```